# Google Tag Manager with Angular 2: Uncaught ReferenceError: osdlfm is not defined

Tags: angular, google-tag-manager

I'm using [Dynamic Component Loading](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html) on [Angular 2](https://angular.io/) for the implementation of many Google Publisher Tag ads and the developer console is showing me sometimes the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: osdlfm is not defined
```

The ads work and are displayed correctly. But I don't want to see those errors.

Comment: Having the same problem with AngularJS

Comment: Having the same problem with React